# symbol endl and cout could not be resolved

Tags: c++, cout, endl

I have written this code from a book i am reading but my complier warns be that symbol cout and endl could not be resolved. Why is that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <float.h>

int main()

{
    cout << "float: " << endl
         << "stevilo decimalnih mest: " << FLT_DIG         << endl
         << "natancnost stevila....: " << FLT_EPSILON      << endl
         << "Najmanjse stevilo.....: " << FLT_MIN          << endl
         << "Najvecje stevilo......: "  << FLT_MAX         << endl
         << "Bitov v mantisi.......: "  << FLT_MANT_DIG    << endl
         << "Najvecji eksponent....: "  << FLT_MAX_10_EXP  << endl
         << "Najmlajsi eksponent...: "  << FLT_MIN_10_EXP  << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 2 options: Use `std::` in front of `cout` / `endl` (preferred way), or `using namespace std;` before `int main ()`.

Comment: An additional option: `using std::cout; using std::endl;`.

Comment: Your book must be ancient or very bad. What's with that `#include <float.h>`, anyway?!

Comment: Please do some research before you post such a question.

Answer (score 0):

`cout` and `endl` are scoped. So you have to inform in which namespace there are.

Use

```
std::cout
std::endl
```

or badly add just after include

```
using namespace std;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use namespace:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <float.h>
using namespace std;
```

or:

```
std::cout
```

You can read more about namespaces in c++ [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/namespaces.html)

Comment: I dont like the phrasing "would have to use namespace". There is really no need to do so. Actually there are good reasons not do it (see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).

Comment: @tobi303 "would have to use(...) OR std::"